# Softwares which compute all non-isomorphic quivers in a mutation class

Tags: quivers, cluster-algebras

Let $Q$ be a quiver. The mutation class of $Q$ consists of all quivers which can be obtained from $Q$ by a sequence of mutations. Are there some softwares which compute all non-isomorphic quivers in a the mutation class of a given quiver? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/). See the method "mutation_class" described [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/cluster_algebra_quiver/quiver.html#sage-combinat-cluster-algebra-quiver-quiver). Below is an example of computing the mutation class of the a directed triangle. See the second link and/or [A compendium on the cluster algebra and quiver package in sage](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4844v2) by Musiker and Stump for more information on how to compute with cluster algebras and quivers in sage.

> sage: Q = ClusterQuiver(DiGraph([[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]]))
>
> sage: C = Q.mutation_class()
>
> sage: for R in C:
>
> ....:     print R.digraph().edges()
>
> ....:     print
>
> ....:
>
> [(0, 2, (1, -1)), (1, 0, (1, -1)), (2, 1, (1, -1))]
>
> [(0, 2, (1, -1)), (2, 1, (1, -1))]
>
> [(0, 1, (1, -1)), (0, 2, (1, -1))]
>
> [(0, 2, (1, -1)), (1, 2, (1, -1))]